# What is the difference between the terms "classical solutions" and "smooth solutions" in the PDE theory?

Tags: terminology, partial-differential-equations

What is the difference between the terms "classical solutions" and "smooth solutions" in the PDE theory? Especially，the difference for the evolution equations? If a solution is in $C^k(0,T;H^m(\Omega))$，can I call it smooth solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A smooth solution is infinitely differentiable. A classical solution is a solution which is differentiable as many times as needed if you want to plug the function into the PDE (for example, if the PDE contains the term $u_{xxxx}$, then the fourth derivate $u_{xxxx}$ must exist in order for $u$ to be a classical solution).

In particular, every smooth solution is a solution in the classical sense. But for the unidirectional wave equation $u_x + u_t = 0$, any function of the form $u(x,t)=f(x-t)$ where $f$ is only (say) twice differentiable, is a classical solution which is not smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :-)

Comment: If a solution is in $C^k(0,T;H^m(\Omega))$，can I call it smooth solution?

Comment: Well, "smooth" usually means $C^{\infty}$, but in some contexts I guess it might mean "smooth enough". As long as you define your terminology you can call it whatever you like. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A classical solution is a function that solves the PDE in the usual sense, ie. $x'=x, x(0)=1 \implies x(t)=e^t$. You can also have weak solutions, which is a variant of the equation with integrals, and is equivalent to the original equation if the solution you are looking at is a classical solution. You can also have solutions as distributions. Look up weak and distribution solutions of Laplace's equation as an example. A smooth solution is one with infinitely many derivatives.
A smooth solution is classical, but a classical solution may not be smooth.