# How to show a 'solution' to an PDE is not classical

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let's assume a solution I found to second order PDE using separation of variables for the wave equation.

The solution is expressed in series: $$u(x,t) = C_0 +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n \cos(\frac{n\pi t}{2})\cos(\frac{nx}{2}) $$

I found the cofficents $C_n$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n $  converges.
I need to show that this solution is not classical solution of the problem.

I guess I have to show that the at least one of the second order derivatives of  $u : u_{xx}, u_{tt} $ does not exist. I'm not sure I know how to do that ? and I wonder what is the meaning of a non-classical solution ?

$C_0 = 0.25, C_n = 0$ for any even $n \in N$
$C_n = \frac{16}{\pi n(16-n^2)}$ for $ n = 1,5,9,\ldots$
$C_n = \frac{-16}{\pi n(16-n^2)}$ for $ n = 3,7,11,\ldots$

the original problem:
$$ u_{tt} = \pi^2u_{xx} ; 0 < x < 2\pi,t>0 $$ 
$$ u(x,0) = f(x), u_t(x,0) = 0; 0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(2\pi,t) = 0; t > 0$$
where $f(x) = sin^2(x)$ between $0$ and $\pi$, and $0$ between $\pi$ and $2\pi$

Comment: thanks. but with respect to this question, I don't know how to show that the derivative does not exist.  I'm not even sure I solved correctly, and my solution is indeed non-classical.

Comment: posted. clearly , I might have mistakes in my solution :(

Comment: thanks for the hint. I wonder if it is ok to say that $u(x,4) = f(x)$ so because $f''(\pi)$ does not exist so $u_{xx}(\pi,4)$ does not exist either ? How can I see that $u_{xx}(\pi,4)$ does not exist directly from the series ?

Comment: thanks. you right. if you want to post your comments as answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is deemed to be a classical solution if it's differentiable as many times as needed to be able to evaluate it in the PDE (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154981/what-is-the-difference-between-the-terms-classical-solutions-and-smooth-solut) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43099/when-can-one-expect-a-classical-solution-of-a-pde) question for more about this). For your $u$ not to be a classical solution of the wave-equation this means that we need to show that $u_{xx}$ and $u_{tt}$ fails to exist at some point $(x,t) \in(0,2\pi) \times (0,\infty)$.

The solution to the wave-equation in this case, with zero initial velocity $u_t(x,0) = 0$, [can be written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D'Alembert's_formula)

$$u(x,t) = \frac{f(x+\pi t) + f(x-\pi t)}{2}$$

where $f(x) = u(x,0)$ is the initial data. The initial data $f(x) = \sin^2(x)\theta(\pi-x)$ for $x\in [0,2\pi]$ has a kink at $x=\pi$ as

$$\lim_{x\to\pi^-} f''(x) = 2,~~~~~\lim_{x\to\pi^+} f''(x) = 0$$

and it follows (in particular) that $u_{xx}(x,t)$ does not exist at any point where $x \pm \pi t = \pi$.